# Why do i get the error unreachable statement?

Tags: java, switch-statement

Why do I get the error that line 92 is an unreachable statement? Basically what I'm trying to do is to skip some of the codes like 21-22-23... if the user inputs something like 11-12-13...

```
import java.util.*;

public class Words {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out. print ("\n\tINTEGER TO WORDS") ;
        System.out.print ("\n\nEnter a number between 1 and 9999: ") ;
        int num = s.nextInt();
        System.out. print ("\nThe answer is: ") ;

        int tho = (num - (num % 1000)) ;            
        int h = (num - tho - (num % 100)) ;
        int t = (num - tho - h -  (num % 10)) ;
        int o = (num - tho - h - t) ;


        switch (tho)
        {
            case 9000:
                System.out.print ("Nine Thousand ") ;
                break ;
            case 8000:
                System.out.print ("Eight Thousand ") ;
                break ;
            case 7000:
                System.out.print ("Seven Thousand ") ;
                break ;
            case 6000:
                System.out.print ("Six Thousand ") ;
                break ;
            case 5000:
                System.out.print ("Five Thousand ") ;
                break ;
            case 4000:
                System.out.print ("Four Thousand ") ;
                break ;
            case 3000:
                System.out.print ("Three Thousand ") ;
                break ;
            case 2000: 
                System.out.print ("Two Thousand ") ;
                break ;
            case 1000: 
                System.out.print ("One Thousand ") ;
                break ;
        }       


        switch (h)
        {
            case 100:
                System.out.print ("One Hundred ") ;
                break ;
            case 200:
                System.out.print ("Two Hundred ") ;
                break ;
            case 300:
                System.out.print ("Three Hundred ") ;
                break ;
            case 400:
                System.out.print ("Four Hundred ") ;
                break ; 
            case 500:
                System.out.print ("Five Hundred ") ;
                break ;
            case 600:
                System.out.print ("Six Hundred ") ;
                break ;
            case 700:
                System.out.print ("Seven Hundred ") ;
                break ;
            case 800:
                System.out.print ("Eight Hundred ") ;
                break ;
            case 900:
                System.out.print ("Nine Hundred ") ;
                break ;
        }

        switch (t)
        {
            case 10:
                System.out.print ("Ten ") ;
                break ;



                **switch (o)** 
                {
                    case 11:
                    System.out.print ("Eleven ") ;
                    break ;
                    case 12:
                    System.out.print ("Twelve ") ;
                    break ;
                    case 13:
                    System.out.print ("Thirteen ") ;
                    break ;
                    case 14:
                    System.out.print ("Fourteen ") ;
                    break ;
                    case 15:
                    System.out.print ("Fifteen ") ;
                    break ;
                    case 16:
                    System.out.print ("Sixteen ") ;
                    break ;
                    case 17:
                    System.out.print ("Seventeen ") ;
                    break ;
                    case 18:
                    System.out.print ("Eighteen ") ;
                    break ;
                    case 19:
                    System.out.print ("Nineteen ") ;
                    break ; 
                }

            case 20:
                System.out.print ("Twenty ") ;
                break ;
            case 30:
                System.out.print ("Thirty") ;
                break ;
            case 40:
                System.out.print ("Fourty ") ;
                break ;
            case 50 :
                System.out.print ("Fifty ") ;
                break ;
            case 60:
                System.out.print ("Sixty ") ;
                break ;
            case 70:
                System.out.print ("Seventy ") ;
                break ;
            case 80:
                System.out.print ("Eighty ") ;
                break ;
            case 90:
                System.out.print ("Ninenty ") ;
                break ;
        }       

        switch (o)
        {
            case 1:
                System.out.print ("One ") ;
                break ;
            case 2:
                System.out.print ("Two ") ;
                break ;
            case 3:
                System.out.print ("Three ") ;
                break ;
            case 4:
                System.out.print ("Four ") ;
                break ;
            case 5:
                System.out.print ("Five ");
                break ;
            case 6:
                System.out.print ("Six ");
                break ;
            case 7:
                System.out.print ("Seven ");
                break ;
            case 8:
                System.out.print ("Eight ");
                break ;
            case 9:
                System.out.print ("Nine ");
                break ;
        }
    System.out. print ("\n") ;  
    }
}
```

Comment: You should read up on and learn to use arrays as a way to simplify and shrink your code greatly.

Comment: `homework` tag added give that switch is "required"

Comment: line numbers would be helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Because you `break` right before it.

Answer (score 6):

Because of the `break;` statement on line 88:

```
case 10:
                System.out.print ("Ten ") ;
                break ; // <-- problem is here



                **switch (o)** 
                {
                    case 11:
                    System.out.print ("Eleven ") ;
```

You're telling the program "skip everything below this expression inside this switch statement until you're out of the switch statement", and the `break` is unconditional, meaning it will *always* occur when inside `case 10`. The compiler is smart enough to recognize that this means, `switch(o)` can never execute, and so it alerts you that the "code cannot be reached".

Comment: Thanks. Last question though, if i enter something like 416 it completely ignores the 11-19 and goes straight to the twenties and ones. What can i do to fix this? So that it will pass through the 11-19 and ignore the 20,30,40 etc.

Answer (score 1):

You've got code in a switch block after a break but without a preceding case, and that is unreachable code.

But seriously, this code is borked and should be scrapped. I recommend you re-write this and use arrays to simplify, plan what you're going to write before you write it and only incrementally add small bits of code at a time, compiling after each bit of code is added and fixing any and all compilation errors before adding any new code.

Comment: Sorry its a requirement to use the switch statement. Thanks for the answer though. :)

Comment: You'll still want to change the way you code, as the code above shows that you're not compiling frequently enough and fixing compile errors before adding code. You should never add new code to a code base that does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your little modified code and tested also.

import java.util.*;

public class Words {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out. print ("\n\tINTEGER TO WORDS") ;
    System.out.print ("\n\nEnter a number between 1 and 9999: ") ;
    int num = s.nextInt();
    System.out. print ("\nThe answer is: ") ;

    int tho = (num - (num % 1000)) ;            
    int h = (num - tho - (num % 100)) ;
    int t=0;
    int o=0;
    if(num>10 && num<20)
    {
        t=num;
    }else{
        t = (num - tho - h -  (num % 10)) ;

         o = (num - tho - h - t) ;

    }


    switch (tho)
    {
        case 9000:
            System.out.print ("Nine Thousand ") ;
            break ;
        case 8000:
            System.out.print ("Eight Thousand ") ;
            break ;
        case 7000:
            System.out.print ("Seven Thousand ") ;
            break ;
        case 6000:
            System.out.print ("Six Thousand ") ;
            break ;
        case 5000:
            System.out.print ("Five Thousand ") ;
            break ;
        case 4000:
            System.out.print ("Four Thousand ") ;
            break ;
        case 3000:
            System.out.print ("Three Thousand ") ;
            break ;
        case 2000: 
            System.out.print ("Two Thousand ") ;
            break ;
        case 1000: 
            System.out.print ("One Thousand ") ;
            break ;
    }       


    switch (h)
    {
        case 100:
            System.out.print ("One Hundred ") ;
            break ;
        case 200:
            System.out.print ("Two Hundred ") ;
            break ;
        case 300:
            System.out.print ("Three Hundred ") ;
            break ;
        case 400:
            System.out.print ("Four Hundred ") ;
            break ; 
        case 500:
            System.out.print ("Five Hundred ") ;
            break ;
        case 600:
            System.out.print ("Six Hundred ") ;
            break ;
        case 700:
            System.out.print ("Seven Hundred ") ;
            break ;
        case 800:
            System.out.print ("Eight Hundred ") ;
            break ;
        case 900:
            System.out.print ("Nine Hundred ") ;
            break ;
    }

    switch (t)
    {
        case 10:
            System.out.print ("Ten ") ;
            break ;

                case 11:
                System.out.print ("Eleven ") ;
                break ;
                case 12:
                System.out.print ("Twelve ") ;
                break ;
                case 13:
                System.out.print ("Thirteen ") ;
                break ;
                case 14:
                System.out.print ("Fourteen ") ;
                break ;
                case 15:
                System.out.print ("Fifteen ") ;
                break ;
                case 16:
                System.out.print ("Sixteen ") ;
                break ;
                case 17:
                System.out.print ("Seventeen ") ;
                break ;
                case 18:
                System.out.print ("Eighteen ") ;
                break ;
                case 19:
                System.out.print ("Nineteen ") ;
                break ; 
        case 20:
            System.out.print ("Twenty ") ;
            break ;
        case 30:
            System.out.print ("Thirty") ;
            break ;
        case 40:
            System.out.print ("Fourty ") ;
            break ;
        case 50 :
            System.out.print ("Fifty ") ;
            break ;
        case 60:
            System.out.print ("Sixty ") ;
            break ;
        case 70:
            System.out.print ("Seventy ") ;
            break ;
        case 80:
            System.out.print ("Eighty ") ;
            break ;
        case 90:
            System.out.print ("Ninenty ") ;
            break ;
    }       

    switch (o)
    {
        case 1:
            System.out.print ("One ") ;
            break ;
        case 2:
            System.out.print ("Two ") ;
            break ;
        case 3:
            System.out.print ("Three ") ;
            break ;
        case 4:
            System.out.print ("Four ") ;
            break ;
        case 5:
            System.out.print ("Five ");
            break ;
        case 6:
            System.out.print ("Six ");
            break ;
        case 7:
            System.out.print ("Seven ");
            break ;
        case 8:
            System.out.print ("Eight ");
            break ;
        case 9:
            System.out.print ("Nine ");
            break ;
    }
System.out. print ("\n") ;  
}
```

}

Comment: It still completely ignores the switch (o) for the 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19. Try typing a number with the teens in it. Sorry to bother. I really appreciate this. :)

Comment: now go through updated code above is updated it will work for you i just tested it.